# Vue - Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js): SyntaxError: Unexpected token (13:1080)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-loader

When i try to run "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./server.js" i got these error:

> ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js):
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token (13:968)

How to fix it. I'm using Vue 2, Webpack 4, and Vue-loader 15.

i've write configuration on my webpack.config and vue.config like this:

```
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");

module.exports = {

  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugins.delete("prefetch");
  },

  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.vue$/,
          loader: "vue-loader"
        },
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          loader: "babel-loader"
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ["vue-style-loader", "css-loader"]
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [new VueLoaderPlugin()],
    resolve: {
      extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx", ".vue", ".ts", ".tsx"],
      alias: {
        vue$: "vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js"
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Do not upload images of code or errors.

Comment: okey @Someone_who_likes_SE i've change it, thank you..

Comment: the problem is probably in a line of your code somewhere - the error should tell you - your configuration file is probably not going to help us determine an error you made somewhere in your code

Comment: ERROR in ./src/views/paket-belajar/Benefit.vue?vue&type=template&id=ce0bd746&scoped=true& (./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/paket-belajar/Benefit.vue?vue&type=template&id=ce0bd746&scoped=true&)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (13:1080)

Comment: i've check my Benefit.vue file, but it looks fine(?)

Comment: The error tells there is an unexpected token somewhere, if you're not using VSCode try getting some plugins/exts for your editor which checks syntax errors (Lints/Linting) on your code "Unexpected token (13:1080) "

Comment: yeah ,it looks fine **to you**, so you post the error rather than the file? - clearly it is not fine - so post the .vue file, we'll tell you where the error is, guaranteed

Comment: oke @Bravo, here i paste my Benefit.vue file that mentioned on error log, please help to check 

https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-lehmann-o0ls0?file=/src/Benefit.vue

Comment: that's a lot of code - any indication what the *Unexpected token* is, or even where in the code the unexpected token is? surely it tells you that at least that

Comment: I must say, it's unusual to see `import` and `require` in the same block of code

Comment: after i trace, i found that when i delete v-if="typeof testimoni === 'object'", there's no more error. 

but why? i put v-if="typeof testimoni === 'object'" inside of "v-if="typeof data === 'object'", am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change line 11 of Benefit.vue from, `this.getData` to simply `getData`

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens when the compilation of a conditional expression gives a complex block of code that the template cannot handle, e.g., when using an optional chaining operator (`?.`).

Moving the expression from the template to a computed property should help.